# Key value pair data structure in R where key length is greater than 1 (multiple keys per value)

Tags: r

Is there a sensible way of storing a mapping of key/value pairs where the key is of length > 1?

#### What I know so far

Where keys are of length 1, we can use a named list, e.g.

```r
mylist <- list(a=c("apple", "alphabet", "allegro"),
               b=c("baseball", "brilliant"))
```

and access the values by using the keys, like so

```
mylist$a
# [1] "apple"    "alphabet" "allegro"
```

But if the keys are of length greater than 1, e.g. instead of `a` and `b`, they were `c('a', 'foo', 'bar')`, and `c('b', 'some', 'thing')`, is there a data structure in R that caters to this many to many mapping, so that any *one* of the elements of a key will map to the relevant values?

Comment: Why would you have keys with duplicate information? Why would you have `foo` and `bar` when all the information you need is already in `a` ?

Comment: @RonakShah in my use case the keys are user input, and users can call things by different names, for example the formal name, but also many slang terms or jargon that means the same thing, so instead of simply using a formal key, I want to have a vector of all possible terms that can mean the same thing

Answer (score 2):

What you want is alternate keys to the same element, from what I understand. This is more a problem in designing the best structure, that something intrinsic to R.

One solution would be to assign the value to each corresponding key, but that would create redundancy, and the value would be repeated.

Another better solution would be to use a pre-list to translate all possible jargons to only which can be used as the key.

So you can have a list of synonyms like:

```
synonyms <- list(jargon1 = "keyword1", jargon2 = "keyword1", jargon3 = "keyword3")
```

So both jargon1 and jargon2 would point to the same keyword which could then be used to fetch the correct value from your main list.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a new `master_list` with the name of all the keys that it can take.

```
master_list <- list(a = c('a', 'foo', 'bar'), b = c('b', 'some', 'thing'))
```

Now the values present in `master_list` can be referred with one common key in `mylist`.

```
mylist <- list(a=c("apple", "alphabet", "allegro"), b=c("baseball", "brilliant"))
```

This will give minimum redundancy overall.